# Delayed evaluation of nested functions

Tags: assignment, machine-precision, nested-function

i am new to Mathematica. Here is the situation:

I have a exponential function of `n,t` that I want to calculate integral over `t` for different values of `n`. I want to define this integral as a function of `n`. I do it with `:=` and it works fine if I provide a number for `n` but if I put a variable lets say `x` it tries to evaluate the integral and get an expression of `x`. This expression leads to precision error and the result for replacing `x` with a number gives zero at the output which is not correct. This is a sample code that I use:

```
A[t_]=Exp[-2.005*10^8 t];
B[n_]:=Integrate[A[t] Exp[-4000 I n \[Pi] t], {t, 0, 1/2000}];
B[0]
B[x]
```

outputs:

```
General:"Exp[-100250.] is too small to represent as a normalized machine \
number; precision may be lost"
4.98753*10^-9
0. + 0. I
```

4.9*10^-9 even if not precise is OK for my application.

I have another function as:

```
C[f_, g_, n_, m_, max_] := 
  ParallelSum[(f /. n :> it ) g /. n :> (m - it), {it, -max, max}];
```

I want to use `B` and another function for example `F` in `C` like

```
F[x_]=1;
G[m_]=C[B[x/5],F[x],x,m,100];
```

Now for every `m` I get zero instead of a very small value. The precision loss is ok for me but I would like to have some value instead of zero to work with in other parts of my application.

Answer (score 2):

If you rationalize `A[t]` integration works

```
A[t_] = Exp[-2.005*10^8 t] // Rationalize[#, 0] &;
B[n_]:=Integrate[A[t] Exp[-4000 I n \[Pi] t], {t, 0, 1/2000}]


B[x] (*-((I - I E^(-100250 - 2 I x \[Pi]))/(4000 (-50125 I + x\[Pi])))*)
B[0] (*(-1 + E^100250)/(200500000 E^100250)*)
```

Comment: The integration by itself works the problem is using `C` even for a large F for example `F[x_] = Exp[100000];`   I get `Exp[-50125.] is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision may be lost` and `0+0I`

Comment: @AminGholizad You might increase `WorkingPrecision` or use an appropriate time scale.

Comment: If I do `C[B[x],F[x],x,m,100];` it gives zero with precision error but if I do `ParallelSum[Integrate[A[t] Exp[-4000 I n \[Pi] t], {t, 0, 1/2000}],F[m-x],{x,-100,100}]` it works as expected.